# assign index and value in separate variable of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array `Array ( ['6'] => mobile )` while i printing my array with `print_r` function of php. I need to separate the index and value of the array in two different variables.

**The actual code is**

```
$ques=$_POST['selector'];
$count = count($ques);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    print_r ($ques)."\n";
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by following way:

```
foreach ($ques as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

Comment: I want to print just the id, but instead of 6 it is printing like '6' . How can i remove single quotations ? note that, I need to assign 6 in the integer form.

Comment: Try to use `echo (int) $key . ' = ' . $value;`.

Comment: every time its printing 0.

Comment: You can replace the quotes by using str_replace function like this: `echo str_replace("'", '', $key);`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php print_r( array_keys( $array ) ); ?>
<?php print_r( array_values( $array ) ); ?>
```

Comment: can i use it like this <?php $id = print_r(array_keys($array)); ?>

Comment: sure, just pass TRUE as a second argument for the print_r function

Comment: You couldn't know until you try running the code. If not working try debugging it.

Comment: after another guess, Are you sure you want the result of the print_r ? or you're just interested in the id of the first element of the array?

Comment: I want to print just the id, but instead of 6 it is printing like '6' . How can i remove single quotations ? note that, I need to assign 6 in the integer form.

Comment: $id = current(array_keys($array));

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($ques as $key => $value) {
    $variable1 = $variable1 . ',' . $key;
    $variable2 = $variable1 . ',' . $value;
}
```

You can then separate the commas with substr if those two variables have more than 1 value.